# CentOS : Packing Kernel into RPM

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kvm

I'm currently using CentOS 6 as a KVM host and will need to customise the kernel to suppport vfio-pci.

Where can I get the spec file for kernel 3.10+ or is there a src.rpm I can download that'll support this feature?

Additionally, I'll also need to patch the kernel with acs override patch and i915 vga arbiter fixes as mentioned in this article: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162768

Here's a thread for the ACS override patch: https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/5/30/513
and for the i915 vga arbiter fix: https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/5/9/517

How to I apply these patches to the kernel? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to move to Fedora as they're more focussed on leading and advancement. I think it's more suited for the system I'm building.

Anyway, if you still interested in building the kernel on CentOS system, here's some of the things you can do.

SRPM of the kernel can be downloaded from ELRepo via the following link: http://elrepo.org/people/ajb/tmp/

However, it doesn't include the source file. You'll need to download this separately at:
https://www.kernel.org/

For the patch files, it's the difference between the source and target files. Save these differences as files. e.g. I would save the code below as a file called doc_kernel_param_patch:

`diff --git a/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt b/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt
index 47bb23c..a60e6ad 100644
--- a/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt
+++ b/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt
@@ -2349,6 +2349,16 @@ bytes respectively. Such letter suffixes can also be entirely omitted.
        nomsi   Do not use MSI for native PCIe PME signaling (this makes
            all PCIe root ports use INTx for all services).`

`+  pcie_acs_override =
+           [PCIE] Override missing PCIe ACS support for:
+       downstream
+           All downstream ports - full ACS capabilties
+       multifunction
+           All multifunction devices - multifunction ACS subset
+       id:nnnn:nnnn
+           Specfic device - full ACS capabilities
+           Specified as vid:did (vendor/device ID) in hex
+
    pcmv=       [HW,PCMCIA] BadgePAD 4`

```
`pd.        [PARIDE]`
```

You'll also need to update the specs file to refer to the patch files created:

`Patch0 doc_kernel_param_patch`

You can now start the build process. For more information refer to the following post:
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=50512